# Understanding warm_start in sklearn MLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

A few notes:

Python Version: `Python 3.5.0`

Sklearn Version: `0.20.3`

I have an [`MLPRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) in the sklearn package that I am using and it achieves rather good results.

The code I am running is below:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import sklearn

def compare_values(arr1, arr2):
    thediff = 0
    thediffs = []
    for thing1, thing2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
        thediff = abs(thing1 - thing2)
        thediffs.append(thediff)

    return thediffs

def robustscale(data):
    scaler = RobustScaler()
    df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(data), columns=data.columns)
    return df_scaled  

total_avgs = []

def driver(data, labels, model, scaling):
    best_model = None
    best = 1000000
    avgs = []

    for x in range(5):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label, shuffle=True, test_size = 0.2)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        preds = model.predict(X_test)
        differences = np.average(compare_values(y_test, preds))
        print("CURRENT MODEL Average: {}".format(differences))
        if differences > best:
            best_model = model
        avgs.append(differences)
        total_avgs.append(differences)

    print("Average Performance Overall: {}".format(np.average(avgs)))
    print("Best Performance Overall: {}".format(np.min(avgs)))

data = pd.read_csv('new.csv')

# handle some data manipulation. Dropping columns and such. Nothing important

data = data
rb_data = robustscale(data)

mlp = MLPRegressor(
    activation = 'tanh',
    hidden_layer_sizes = (1000, 1000, 1000),
    alpha = 0.009,
    learning_rate = 'invscaling',
    learning_rate_init = 0.01,
    max_iter = 200,
    momentum = 0.9,
    solver = 'lbfgs',
    warm_start = False
)

print("############################################")
print("NOW TESTING ROBUST SCALE DATA: ")
driver(rb_data, label, mlp, "rb")
print("############################################")

print("\n")

print("BEST MODEL PERFORMANCE: {}".format(np.min(total_avgs)))
```

I am trying to understand *why* I am getting such good results for a regression problem.

My MLP is configured as such (parameters selected after utilizing [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html))

```
mlp = MLPRegressor(
    activation = 'tanh',
    hidden_layer_sizes = (1000, 1000, 1000),
    alpha = 0.009,
    learning_rate = 'invscaling',
    learning_rate_init = 0.01,
    max_iter = 200,
    momentum = 0.9,
    solver = 'lbfgs',
    warm_start = True
)
```

(Yes, I too found it odd `relu` was not selected. But it never was)

When I set [`warm_start = True`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-warm-start), I get output like the following:

```
############################################
NOW TESTING ROBUST SCALE DATA:
CURRENT MODEL Average: 21.163831505120193
CURRENT MODEL Average: 12.44361687293673
CURRENT MODEL Average: 5.687720697116947
CURRENT MODEL Average: 4.225979713815092
CURRENT MODEL Average: 5.235999000929669
Average Performance Overall: 9.751429557983725
Best Performance Overall: 4.225979713815092
############################################
```

Clearly, the performance is getting better with each run.

However, when I set `warm_start = False`, I get:

```
############################################
NOW TESTING ROBUST SCALE DATA: 
CURRENT MODEL Average: 25.221720858740714
CURRENT MODEL Average: 20.3609370299473
CURRENT MODEL Average: 23.385534335200845
CURRENT MODEL Average: 21.89668702232435
CURRENT MODEL Average: 15.38606220618026
Average Performance Overall: 21.250188290478693
Best Performance Overall: 15.38606220618026
############################################
```

So clearly, `warm_start = True` is affecting performance in a positive way. But *how*? In each run of the loop, I am resplitting my data randomly, creating a **brand new** model, and running the tests. How could the new model be learning from the old?

Comment: From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html), you are creating a new model, but telling the regressor to "reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization". Apologies, but it's not entirely clear what clarification you're asking for

Comment: I have read the docs, too. I guess what I don't understand is the quoted line. How does a _new_ model know anything about the previous instantiation? Hypothetically, if I ran this 1000 times, wouldn't my data simply just overfit, and not be that tuned? I guess I don't understand *how a new model learns from a previous*, and how *overfitting can come of that*

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation is that your model has 'seen' the data you are testing in each loop, and has a 'memory' of them. In other words your test data is not independent from your training data anymore when you use warm start and that's why you get unrealistically good results. You shouldn't use warm start if you are trying cross-validation settings. Test data should be kept away from spliting and also scaling. Scaling the whole dataset prior to split and training has similar effect of 'leaking' data between train and test portions. Take a look here as well:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline

Answer (score -1):

> In each run of the loop, I am resplitting my data randomly, creating a brand new model, and running the tests.

No, you're not creating a brand new model! The model is being created only once, by the constructor.